# UITableViewDataSource responds, but delegate doesn't

Tags: ios, uitableview

I have a tableview in a nib file, that has the datasource and delegate set to file's owner.  It also has an outlet set to an IBOutlet property declared in the class.  All of the datasource methods responds as one would expect.  None of the delegate methods respond.

I have gone through everything I can think of so far: deleting the tableview, adding another, clicking and unclicking the datasource and delegate connections, you name it.  Always the same.

I have a tap gesture recognizer on the main view, and the delegate set to self.  So when a tap comes in, I'm able to intercept it in the gesture recognizer delegate method, and the tap is indeed coming from a table view cell.  This is recognized as a tap from within the table, and so the method returns NO to tell the gesture recognizer not to respond.

Any thoughts?

Comment: Are all the delegate methods not working?

Comment: What delegate methods have you implemented? If you comment out the tap gesture recognizer that you've added does didSelectRowAtIndexPath get called when you tap a row?

Comment: could you add the code for your .h file, specifically the @interface line?

Comment: None of the delegate methods we tried worked, but see my answer below.

Answer (score 0):

Well, we tried everything.  Shutting down Xcode, blowing the environment away and re-checking out the code, shutting down the machine, nothing.

Copied those files to another machine, and it works.

Clueless...